# How can i specify docker run argument in azure container creation

Tags: azure, docker, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

When I run docker locally I specify the ipc argument equal to host in order to avoid insufficient shared memory problem.
`docker run -it --name visdrone_cpu -p 8000:8000 --ipc host visdrone`.

How can I replicate this in azure during the container creation?

`az container create -g visdrone -n visdrone --image sergiocaputoo/visdrone --port 80 --ipc host                       unrecognized arguments: --ipc host`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the research, we understood that IPC (POSIX/SysV IPC) namespace provides separation of named shared memory segments, semaphores and message queues.Shared memory segments are used to accelerate inter-process communication at memory speed, rather than through pipes or through the network stack.

> az container create -g visdrone -n visdrone --image sergiocaputoo/visdrone --port 80 --ipc host >unrecognized arguments: --ipc host

As per the current Azure CLI [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create),We dont have any parameter `--ipc` can be used in the `az container create` cmdlet for creating a container group.

Container group is a collection of containers running on the same host and sharing the same resources and life cycle. The concept is very similar to the pod in Kubernetes.

You can use this sample cmdlet to Create a container in a container group that runs Windows, with 2 cores and 3.5Gb of memory.

```
az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name mywinapp --image winappimage:latest --os-type Windows --cpu 2 --memory 3.5
```